# combine results of 2 result sets with common attribute mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join, select

I am trying to combine two result sets that were obtained using SQL queries into a single result set. The sets have 2 columns each. The first set contains Nickname and posts while the other one is Nickname and comments. How do I combine these two sets to display how much posts and comments each nickname has? The final result set should contain: Nickname, posts, comments.

First set:

```
SELECT u.nickname, COUNT(c.nickname) AS comments 
 FROM postcomments c, users u WHERE c.nickname = u.nickname 
GROUP BY nickname;
```

Second set:

```
SELECT u.nickname, COUNT(*) AS posts 
 FROM postauthors a, users u WHERE a.nickname = u.nickname 
GROUP BY u.nickname;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` to do it

```
SELECT u.nickname, COUNT(c.id) AS comments,count(a.id) AS posts 
 FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN postcomments c ON c.nickname = u.nickname
 LEFT JOIN postauthors a ON a.nickname=u.nickname
GROUP BY u.nickname;
```